# Automatically trim a bitmap to minimum size?

Tags: c#, image-processing, bitmap, gdi+

Suppose I have a `System.Drawing.Bitmap` in 32bpp ARGB mode. It's a large bitmap, but it's mostly fully transparent pixels with a relatively small image somewhere in the middle.

What is a fast algorithm to detect the borders of the "real" image, so I can crop away all the transparent pixels from around it?

Alternatively, is there a function already in .Net that I can use for this?

Comment: Is the cutoff straight?  if so, reading pixels from L->R and T->B would work very quick.

Comment: If it is square, you can probably save even more time and binary search it from center out on all 4 sides (at least cutting down on pixel interrogations)

Comment: Can the small, embedded image also have transparent pixels within it?

Comment: Unfortunately, the image can be any shape.

Comment: @Andrew: yes, it could have transparent pixels inside it as well.

Comment: i don't see a way of doing this better than O(n^2)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The basic idea is to check every pixel of the image to find the top, left, right and bottom bounds of the image. To do this efficiently, don't use the `GetPixel` method, which is pretty slow. Use `LockBits` instead.

Here's the implementation I came up with:

```
static Bitmap TrimBitmap(Bitmap source)
{
    Rectangle srcRect = default(Rectangle);
    BitmapData data = null;
    try
    {
        data = source.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, source.Width, source.Height), ImageLockMode.ReadOnly, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);
        byte[] buffer = new byte[data.Height * data.Stride];
        Marshal.Copy(data.Scan0, buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
        int xMin = int.MaxValue;
        int xMax = 0;
        int yMin = int.MaxValue;
        int yMax = 0;
        for (int y = 0; y < data.Height; y++)
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < data.Width; x++)
            {
                byte alpha = buffer[y * data.Stride + 4 * x + 3];
                if (alpha != 0)
                {
                    if (x < xMin) xMin = x;
                    if (x > xMax) xMax = x;
                    if (y < yMin) yMin = y;
                    if (y > yMax) yMax = y;
                }
            }
        }
        if (xMax < xMin || yMax < yMin)
        {
            // Image is empty...
            return null;
        }
        srcRect = Rectangle.FromLTRB(xMin, yMin, xMax, yMax);
    }
    finally
    {
        if (data != null)
            source.UnlockBits(data);
    }

    Bitmap dest = new Bitmap(srcRect.Width, srcRect.Height);
    Rectangle destRect = new Rectangle(0, 0, srcRect.Width, srcRect.Height);
    using (Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(dest))
    {
        graphics.DrawImage(source, destRect, srcRect, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
    }
    return dest;
}
```

It can probably be optimized, but I'm not a GDI+ expert, so it's the best I can do without further research...

---

EDIT: actually, there's a simple way to optimize it, by not scanning some parts of the image :

1. scan left to right until you find a non-transparent pixel; store (x, y) into (xMin, yMin)
2. scan top to bottom until you find a non-transparent pixel (only for x >= xMin); store y into yMin
3. scan right to left until you find a non-transparent pixel (only for y >= yMin); store x into xMax
4. scan bottom to top until you find a non-transparent pixel (only for xMin <= x <= xMax); store y into yMax

---

EDIT2: here's an implementation of the approach above:

```
static Bitmap TrimBitmap(Bitmap source)
{
    Rectangle srcRect = default(Rectangle);
    BitmapData data = null;
    try
    {
        data = source.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, source.Width, source.Height), ImageLockMode.ReadOnly, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);
        byte[] buffer = new byte[data.Height * data.Stride];
        Marshal.Copy(data.Scan0, buffer, 0, buffer.Length);

        int xMin = int.MaxValue,
            xMax = int.MinValue,
            yMin = int.MaxValue,
            yMax = int.MinValue;

        bool foundPixel = false;

        // Find xMin
        for (int x = 0; x < data.Width; x++)
        {
            bool stop = false;
            for (int y = 0; y < data.Height; y++)
            {
                byte alpha = buffer[y * data.Stride + 4 * x + 3];
                if (alpha != 0)
                {
                    xMin = x;
                    stop = true;
                    foundPixel = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (stop)
                break;
        }

        // Image is empty...
        if (!foundPixel)
            return null;

        // Find yMin
        for (int y = 0; y < data.Height; y++)
        {
            bool stop = false;
            for (int x = xMin; x < data.Width; x++)
            {
                byte alpha = buffer[y * data.Stride + 4 * x + 3];
                if (alpha != 0)
                {
                    yMin = y;
                    stop = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (stop)
                break;
        }

        // Find xMax
        for (int x = data.Width - 1; x >= xMin; x--)
        {
            bool stop = false;
            for (int y = yMin; y < data.Height; y++)
            {
                byte alpha = buffer[y * data.Stride + 4 * x + 3];
                if (alpha != 0)
                {
                    xMax = x;
                    stop = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (stop)
                break;
        }

        // Find yMax
        for (int y = data.Height - 1; y >= yMin; y--)
        {
            bool stop = false;
            for (int x = xMin; x <= xMax; x++)
            {
                byte alpha = buffer[y * data.Stride + 4 * x + 3];
                if (alpha != 0)
                {
                    yMax = y;
                    stop = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (stop)
                break;
        }

        srcRect = Rectangle.FromLTRB(xMin, yMin, xMax, yMax);
    }
    finally
    {
        if (data != null)
            source.UnlockBits(data);
    }

    Bitmap dest = new Bitmap(srcRect.Width, srcRect.Height);
    Rectangle destRect = new Rectangle(0, 0, srcRect.Width, srcRect.Height);
    using (Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(dest))
    {
        graphics.DrawImage(source, destRect, srcRect, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
    }
    return dest;
}
```

There won't be a significant gain if the non-transparent part is small of course, since it will still scan most of the pixels. But if it's big, only the rectangles around the non-transparent part will be scanned.

Comment: BTW, I just realized there is a simpler way to crop the image, without using a Graphics: `return source.Clone(srcRect, source.PixelFormat);`

Comment: Great solution, very helpful, but I found my images were getting clipped by one pixel too many. Logically yours seems right, but I changed the call to **Rectangle.FromLTRB** to **srcRect = Rectangle.FromLTRB(xMin, yMin, xMax + 1, yMax + 1)** and now it works perfectly.

Comment: Thanks for the code! `default(Rectangle)` is wrong too, though. Windows doesn't allow Bitmaps with less than one pixel. It try fails, etc.

Comment: @Bitterblue, it doesn't matter, because the initial value of `srcRect` is always overwritten before it is used.

Comment: @ThomasLevesque No it is **not always** overwritten. For example  `data = source.LockBits(...);` can throw an exception and `srcRect = ...` is at the very end of try-block. Like I misspelled to say (^^): "if try fails, etc."

Comment: @Bitterblue, if it throws in the `try` block, then the `finally` block will be executed, and the exception will propagate up the stack. The place where `srcRect` is used will never be reached.

Answer (score 1):

I would like to suggest a divide & conquer approach:

1. split the image in the middle (e.g. vertically)
2. check if there are non-transparent pixels on the cut line (if so, remember min/max for bounding box)
3. split left half again vertically
4. if cut line contains non-transparent pixels -> update bounding box
5. if not, you can probably discard the leftmost half (I don't know the pictures)
6. continue with the left-right half (you stated that the image is somewhere in the middle) until you find the leftmost bound of the image
7. do the same for the right half

Comment: I think your 5th point is wrong: there could be several distinct areas with non-transparent pixels, so the fact there is no non-transparent pixel on the cut line doesn't mean anything

Comment: Thanks bjoernz, but yeah: binary search will not always work for my images - it's possible there could be two images separated by whitespace, for example.